# how to use objects created within the parent class in the child class PHP

Tags: php

I have this code and i´m trying to use a object

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public $_view;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_view = new View();
        return $this->_view;

    }

}




class View {


    public $_params = array ();


    public function set_params($index_name,$valores) {
        $this->_params[$index_name] = $valores;
    }

    public function get_param($index_name){
        return $this->_params[$index_name];
    }
}

?>
```

i would like to do this:

```
class Index extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $model = Model::get_estancia();
        $usuarios = $model->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
        $this->_view->set_params();   // cant be used.
        $this->load_view("index/index");

    }
}
```

i would like to use the set_parms function.
but i can't see the View Function, then i can not use.
Can someone explain and advise me a good and safe way?

Comment: Constructors don't return.  Remove that line from your Controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correction from Phil**: If a __construct() method isn't found, PHP will revert to legacy constructor syntax and check for a method with the same name as the object. In your case the method `index()` is being treated as the constructor, and is preventing the parent's constructor from loading the view object into the $_view property.

You can force a class to inherit a parent's constructor by defining `__construct()` in the child and calling the parent's constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::_construct();
}
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public $_view;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_view = new View();
        return $this->_view;

    }

}
```

.

```
class View {


    public $_params = array ();


    public function set_params($index_name,$valores) {
        $this->_params[$index_name] = $valores;
    }

    public function get_param($index_name){
        return $this->_params[$index_name];
    }
}
```

.

```
class Index extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index() {
        $model = Model::get_estancia();
        $usuarios = $model->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
        $this->_view->set_params();   // cant be used.
        $this->load_view("index/index");

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. PHP constructors are inherited by extending classes. The problem is the name of the `index` method on the `Index` class. This is being interpreted as a constructor via the legacy constructor name syntax.

Comment: Adding a `__construct` method to `Index` (as you have done) is the way around the above mentioned limitation as this takes precedence as a constructor method

Comment: You're right, thanks. I tested the code, thought the class must not be inheriting the constructor, and a bad Google search result told me magic methods aren't inherited. This was an interesting one for me!

Comment: @Phil, You helped me alot, thank you ! This is what i was want.

Comment: One more thing, is pretty simple. I've tidied up the code thanks for your help, but how can I get the IDE show me the method of the Controller class, which in turn is creating a resort class view?

For example:
  In NetBeans when you write "$ this->" it now shows all the available methods of class and class that inherited. Why it does not show the methods instantiated ($ _view) used in the parent, which in the case show the methodos of view?

Comment: @user2824425 You just need to set up the right type-hints. Search for a relevant question or ask a new one.